# Give ul a class for image gallery, so that other uls on page aren't affected

Tags: css, class, overlay, html-lists, image-gallery

My site has a header with a ul (with links) for the navigation bar.

[image: (link to image below - 1)]

One of my pages has a ul for an image gallery. The template for that is from this website: http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/v3/

The image gallery does what I want it to: opens an enlarged picture over the page when clicked (overlay), the enlarged picture is centered, and closes when clicking anywhere on the screen. The problem is that the ul messes up my navigation bar. How do I fix that? The nav bar already has a ul class.

[image: (link to image below - 2)]

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
ul li{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin:0.3em;
border:0.1em solid black;
-webkit-border-radius:0.25em;
-moz-border-radius:0.25em;
border-radius:0.25em;
}
ul li:hover { border:0.1em solid red; }

ul li img, ul li label { 
    display: block; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}

ul li input { display: none; }
ul li input:checked + .overlay { display: table; }

.overlay{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
display: none; 
z-index: 999;
background: rgb(0,0,0);
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);}

.overlay label
{
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
}
    .overlay img,
    .overlay iframe
    {
        display: inline;
        border:0.25em solid white;
        -webkit-border-radius:0.25em;
        -moz-border-radius:0.25em;
        border-radius:0.25em;
    }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="text2col">
        <h2>Photo gallery</h2>

<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="futurebox01"><img src="http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/gr_ninja-attack_med.gif" width="100" height="102" alt="The CSS Ninja" /></label>
        <input type="radio" id="futurebox01" name="gallery" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <label for="close" title="Close futurebox"><img src="http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/gr_cssninja_lrg.png" alt="The Css Ninja" width="469" height="500" /></label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="futurebox02"><img src="http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/gr_ninja-attack_med.gif" width="100" height="102" alt="The CSS Ninja" /></label>
        <input type="radio" id="futurebox02" name="gallery" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <label for="close" title="Close futurebox"><img src="http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/gr_cssninja_lrg2.png" alt="The Css Ninja" width="469" height="500" /></label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="futurebox03"><img src="http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/gr_ninja-attack_med.gif" width="100" height="102" alt="The CSS Ninja" /></label>
        <input type="radio" id="futurebox03" name="gallery" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <label for="close" title="Close futurebox"><img src="http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/gr_cssninja_lrg3.png" alt="The Css Ninja" width="469" height="500" /></label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="futurebox04"><img src="http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/gr_ninja-attack_med.gif" width="100" height="102" alt="The CSS Ninja" /></label>
        <input type="radio" id="futurebox04" name="gallery" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <label for="close" title="Close futurebox"><img src="http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/gr_cssninja_lrg4.png" alt="The Css Ninja" width="469" height="500" /></label>
        </div>
    </li>
... (more li's)...
</ul>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

<input type="radio" id="close" name="gallery" />
```

I also tried to add a ul class for the image gallery, by changing all the `ul` to `ul.futurebox` and adding that into the class into the webpage, and that made the nav bar go back to normal BUT then it no longer centers the overlay image (the overlay is there, but the image goes to the top, left of the page).

[image: (link to image below - 3)]

The problem (I think) is that there's an adjacent sibling connector with the overlay: `ul li input:checked + .overlay { display: table; }` So after adding a class for the image gallery.  Or... it might be another problem entirely, but I'm not sure.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYU1K.png
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rMi5n.png
[3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ffDWP.png

Comment: You gave the CSS, but no HTML. That would really help in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Here us a good pattern to follow for list-based menus: http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists/

Comment: @Scott, thanks. I've added the HTML. Also, the webpage where the header is messed up but the image gallery is good: http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/intheclassroom/photogallery7.cfm and the webpage where the header is good but the image gallery is messed up: http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/intheclassroom/photogallery7.1.cfm

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an answer, but this demo does everything I want it to do: http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/futurebox/

It doesn't have the adjacent sibling connector, so I used this as a template, and put in a ul class called "futurebox" for the image gallery, so that my nav bar wouldn't be affected.

Except the problem with this one is that it goes through all the images you clicked through with the "back" button, whereas the other one didn't.